# Принцип преобразования указателя в итератор?

Tags: c++

Недавно потребовалось преобразовать указатель в итератор. На просторах SO - нашел вот такой ответ:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55687896/8212170

В нем, мне не до конца понятен синтаксис преобразования указателя в итератор:

```
itr = (std::vector<int>::iterator&)(*ptr);  //cast pointer back to iterator
```

- я вижу явное преобразование в стиле С, но не могу понять,что означает связка вида:

```
iterator&)(*ptr)
```

- т.е `(*ptr)` в мы разыименовали указатель, получили значение, но как это соотносится с `iterator&` - не совсем понимаю, что это за синтаксис, т.к на оператор взятия адресса - это не похоже.

Comment: Это ссылка, те приведение к ссылке на итератор(вектора int)

Comment: О каком указателе идет речь? Указатель на что? О каком итераторе идет речь? С чего это вдруг вообще зашла речь о каком-то преобразовании одного в другое? Потрудитесь вменяемо сформулировть вопрос.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Тот ответ, что вы прилинковали по ссылке - вообще бессмысленный набор символов,  никакого отношения к преобразованию указателя в итератор не имеющий.

Comment: @AnT, не могли бы Вы мне объяснить(нет, я серьезно), что на SO - вообще считается осмысленным?! Не приводишь пример - плохо, приводишь пример с авторитетного источника (будет странно, если на SO скажут, что SO -не авторитетный) , причем не заминусованный ответ, который сработал на практике (я проверил) -  и тебе говорят, что "ты дурак" (утрирование) и "ответ дурацкий" . Я иногда вообще не понимаю принцип вопроса на SO ? Уже и сформулировал лаконично и источник привел... Т.е получается, что бы грамотно задать вопрос, я должен заранее знать на него ответ, что бы отличить "бред" от хор. примера?

Comment: @AnT -прошу не считать за оскорбление, ничего личного.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Пока в вопросе присутствует только пара огрызков, явно бессмысленных без контекста. PS (поглядел страницу по ссылке) - они бессмысленные даже в контексте того вопроса. А преобразовать указатель в итератор в общем случае нельзя.

Comment: @BadCatss: Во-первых,  в вашем вопросе не сказано, что вы хотите задать тот же вопрос, что и по ссылке. Во-вторых, вопрос по ссылке сформулирован криво и бессмысленно: совершенно не ясно куда указывает этот `id` и можно ли вообще его преобразовать в итератор. Нет, скажем прямо: там в вопросе написана полная бредятина. Поэтому оставьте в покое эту ссылку и сформулируйте свой вопрос самостоятельно. О каких указателях и итераторах вообще идет речь?

Comment: "списка или вектора"? Так "списка или вектора" или только "вектора"?

Comment: @BadCatss, поменьше доверяйте ответам на SO, даже с плюсами и галками о принятии.

Comment: С вектором, в принципе, должен сработать простой трюк `v.begin() + (ptr - v.data())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У итератора вектора есть перегрузка operator+, поэтому правильно будет так:

```
void AddCarAt(Car car, int index)
{
    Car_list.insert(Car_list.begin() + index, car);
}
```

Comment: Стоит отметить, что никакого преобразования указателя в итератор тут не  происходит.

Comment: Также ничего подобного со списком провернуть не получится.

Answer (score 4):

1. Не ясно, почему в заголовке вопроса вообще идет речь о каких-то "указателях", если задача состоит в том, чтобы осуществить вставку в конкретную позицию контейнера. По сути задачи, речь идет о преобразовании индекса в итератор. Откуда вообще в этом вопросе возникло упоминание каких-то "указателей"?
2. Нет, ваш подход не правилен. Что такое `Car_list.begin()._Ptr` и для чего вы пытаетесь применить преобразование к ссылочному типу - не ясно. Этот какая-то белиберда.
3. Вы ведете речь о "списке или векторе". Список и вектор - контейнеры совершенно различной природы и задача вставки по конкретному индексу для вектора и для списка - совершенно разные по своей природе задачи.
4. Вектор (`std::vector`) - контейнер с произвольным доступом, поддерживающий эффективный доступ по индексу. Соответственно итераторы вектора являются *итераторами произвольного доступа*. Такие итераторы поддерживают эффективную итераторную арифметику. Индекс элемента контейнера может быть мгновенно преобразован в соответствующий итератор при помощи итераторной арифметики от итератора `begin()`, т.е. просто при помощи бинарного оператора `+`

   ```
     std::vector<Car> car_list;
     int i = ...;                    // индекс
     auto it = car_list.begin() + i; // соответствующий итератор
   ```
5. Список (`std::list`) - контейнер последовательного (двухсвязного) доступа, не поддерживающий эффективного доступа по индексу. Итераторы списка не являются итераторами произвольного доступа. Преобразовать индекс элемента в соответствующий итератор при помощи простого применения оператора `+` не получится. Единственный способ - последовательный проход по всем элементам/итераторам контейнера от начала до требуемой позиции, что по понятным причинам в общем случае неэффективно. Однако если вы все таки хотите это сделать, то в стандартной библиотеке такой проход можно осуществить при помощи функций `std::advance` или `std::next`

   ```
     std::list<Car> car_list;
     int i = ...;                              // индекс
     auto it = std::next(car_list.begin(), i); // соответствующий итератор
   ```
6. Функции `std::advance` или `std::next` умеют различать, с каким типом итератора ни имеют дело. Для итератора произвольного доступа они сразу применят оператор `+`, как в пункте 4, т.е. не будут выполнять неэффективный пересчет элементов контейнера тогда, когда это не нужно. Это значит, что при работе с вектором тоже можно было воспользоваться функцией `std::next`, как в пункте 5, и получить единообразный код, подходящий для обоих типов контейнеров. Однако этот совсем не означает, что таким функциями следует пользоваться везде. Эти функции фактически предоставляют вам возможность скрывать неэффективный код.